# migrate htaccess rewrite to nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the followinf rewrite rule on htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^?]+?)(?:\.php)?\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

The rule redirects "lang" parameter to subdirectory:
http://www.www.www/somepage?lang=en -> http://www.www.www/en/somepage

How can i create the same rule on NGINX ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please place following Rules into your nginx Rule file. I have placed a file named so_question in path `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and ran the service on `8081` in my localhost and these worked perfectly fine(tested by `curl` command). By the way I am no expert in nginx, I spent ample amount in learning to solve this :) I hope this helps.

As per your shown htaccess this assumes you want to redirect a url from `http://localhost:8181/test.php?lang=en_abc123_singhblabla` TO `http://localhost:8181/en_abc123_singhblabla-test`(mentioned this in comments also inside Rule file).

```
cat so_question
server {
       listen 8181;
       listen [::]:8181 ipv6only=on default_server;
       server_name localhost;

##Actual redirect rule which redirects from a URL eg-->
##http://localhost:8181/test.php?lang=en_abc123_singhblabla -->
##http://localhost:8181/en_abc123_singhblabla-test


if ($request_uri ~ "^/([^.]*)\.php\?lang=(.*)") {
    set $original_path $1;
    set $args1 $2;
    set $args "";

    rewrite ^ "$scheme://$host/${args1}-${original_path}" permanent;
}

}
```